# How do I implement the Words associated type for the BinaryInteger protocol?

Tags: arrays, swift, endianness, bignum

I am trying to make a BigNumber library for Swift, that represents numbers with an array of UInt64's. I am trying to conform my UBigNumber struct to BinaryInteger, which means I must have the associated type `Words`. I implement it like this:

```swift
/// Words type of `UBigNumber`
public typealias Words = [UInt64]
```

but then I eventually get the error:

```
'BinaryInteger' requires the types 'UInt64' and 'UInt' be equivalent
```

with an extra tidbit telling me:

```
Requirement specified as 'Self.Words.Element' == 'UInt' [with Self = UBigNumber]
```

I am not sure what these errors mean or how to correct them. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think your words have to have type `[UInt]`... a machine word is a machine dependently sized integer type.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica So does this mean the actual sizes of the numbers may be different on different machines? I want to enforce it being ```[UInt64]```

Comment: The `words` computed property is intentionally made to return an array of machine-word-sized-integers (`UInt64`), to allow for efficient manipulation of the memory underpinning your binary integer. It's a computed property, so nothing is stopping you from implementing the underlying storage in whatever way you want. Heck, you could implement a `Int1` that stores its value as a bool, and whose words property returns `self.bool ? [1] : [0]`